# Kannel is sending Arabic characters as question marks

Tags: sms, sendmessage, modem, kannel

I connected my Ubuntu server to USB modem d-link 
it works very fine in English but it sends sms in arabic characters as question marks 
 kannel send sms url that I use in my laravel code
 `http://192.168.1.30/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=nnn&password=nnn&to=mynumber&text=y&charset=utf-8&coding=2`

Comment: Try changing the order of the parmeters. For instance charset and coding first and the then the text at the end.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your link charset=UTF-8&coding=2&text=It%27s%20a%20miracle,%20it%20just%20work!